# How to stop the same data from being added to local storage

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

Hi im farily new to javascript and i would like to know a simple method of 
how i can make sure that i can only favourate an item once else it doesnt get added to the local storage and displays a message stating it already exists.
so far i have done the following :

```
$(".add").on( "click", function() {
            try {
                $(this).attr('disabled', true);
                var IdToAdd = $(this).closest("p").attr("id");
                var myFavStaff = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("favStaff"));
                if (myFavStaff == null) {
                    myFavStaff = [];
                }
                myFavStaff .push(IdToAdd );
                localStorage.setItem("favStaff", JSON.stringify(myFavStaff ));
            }
            catch (e) {
                if (e == QUOTA_EXCEEDED_ERR) {
                    console.log("Error: Local Storage limit exceeded" );
                } else {
                    console.log("Error: Saving to local storage not working" );
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: store an object keyed by id instead of an array, keys can't be re-used...

Answer (score 0):

With the technique you are using you will need to check the array before adding a new ID to it. For example you could do something like this.

```
if (myFavStuff.indexOf(IdToAdd) !== -1) {
     // Already exists so show a message
} else {
    myFavStuff.push(IdToAdd);
    localStorage.setItem("favStaff", JSON.stringify(myFavStaff ));
}
```

Comment: Glad I could help. Feel free to accept the answer :)